# How to limit page scroll to the div with the least amount of content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i wish to limit the page of the scroll of my page to the end of content on the right div. The left div has a larger content but i want the page scroll to stop at the right div's and the left div to continue scroll within its area. I have the following script but it doesnt really seem to work:

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
    var i=10000000;
    var buff='';
    while(--i){
        buff+='<br />';
    }
    document.body.innerHTML=buff;
}  
</script>
```

[image: Here] an idea of what the problem is..

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do it with CSS and `position:fixed` ? (I could provide you more code if you'd gave us some)

Comment: HTML + CSS of your right div (not the whole HTML but the opening/closing markers at least)

Comment: @lekiss i think you can try telling me how can i fixed the position through css first then i try then i can't i shall paste the code?

Comment: Add a `position:fixed` and see what's happening... I hope you don't expect me to write all your code :3

Comment: @lekiss of course..i would go and try it myself but judging from experience i doubt that would work